# Problem while running parallel test with Firefox profile!

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

Iam using selenium 1.0.3 RC (java client ).also iam using firefox
profile to run Firefox.

while running tests in parallel ,some times it says

"Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new
window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart
your system."

Answer (score 1):

Use selenium grid to run test cases on different environment.
if dont want to use grid start selenium server on different ports.
in your script add following line

```
this.setPort(444x)
```

in place of x put your started port number example 4445 for the code which you want to fire on the port

Comment: iam already starting the servers at different port and running parallely,the problem is when i run the test ,sometimes firefox shows above error.

Comment: are you properly setting the port number in the code as i am able to run successfully at my end.

Comment: Yes, i added 3 test cases in my suite and executed twice parallel

Comment: problem is when i run cases in parrarell with firefox profile template. It occurs mostly not always.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open Firefox profile icon used to start Firefox with a text editor, look in it for -no-remote and delete that (only the "-no-remote")